# Two Table difference without using column name

Tags: mysql

I have to return all the rows/count of rows which are different in comparing two tables.

I found except in sql. Is there any thing in mysql like except or intersect in mysql?

I know It can be done using query having columns name in list, but I don't want to use columns name.

My Example

### Table 1

```
|column1|column2|column3|column4|column5|column6|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+    
|Value 1|Value 2|Value 3|Value 4|Value 5|Value 6|     
|Value 1|Value 2|Value 3|Value 4|Value 5|Value 6|     
|Value 1|Value 2|Value 3|Value 4|Value 5|Value 6|     
|Value 1|Value 2|Value 3|Value 4|Value 5|Value 6|     
|Value 1|Value 2|Value 3|Value 4|Value 5|Value 6|
```

### Table 2

```
|column1|column2|column3|column4|column5|column6|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+     
|Value 1|Value 2|Value 3|Value 4|Value 5|Value 6|     
|Value 1|Value 2|Value 3|Value 4|Value 5|Value 6|     
|Value 1|Value 2|Value 3|Value 4|Value 5|Value 6|     
|Value 1|Value 2|Value 3|Value 4|Value 5|Value 6|     
|Value 1|Value 2|Value 3|Value 4|Value 5|Value 6|
```

Can it be achieved with using only table name?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there isn't known column names you can use [`NATURAL LEFT JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html):

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM table1 t1
  NATURAL LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.*, 1 AS some_magic_name FROM table2 t2) t2
  WHERE t2.some_magic_name IS NULL
UNION
SELECT t2.*
  FROM table2 t2
  NATURAL LEFT JOIN (SELECT t1.*, 1 AS some_magic_name FROM table1 t1) t1
  WHERE t1.some_magic_name IS NULL
```

There is [working sample on **SQL Fidle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/903d1/2).

Comment: Yes this could work.. But if you have very big collections of data, wouldnt it a bad idea to do a search on every single field of the tables, and do this actually 2 times for every field? The query seems nice.. and very useful.. But i'm afraid this would be a big performance hit if you use it on big tables.

Comment: It's look likes no: "You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query": http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/temporary-table-problems.html

Comment: So is there any way to do that, because basically i have to compare on two result set, rather than writing query multiple times is there way to accomplish straightway

Comment: This throws Can't reopen table: 'table2'

Comment: The error is because of strange TEMPORARY table limitation in MySQL (mentioned in earlier comment). You can use one of these workarounds: 1) use `VIEWS` instead of temporary tables; or 2) create second copies of temporary tables and refer to them in second `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can archieve this by building both queries based on the scheme, then union them together.. group by on all fields and condition count(*) to 1. A simple example down here (full sql):

```
set @tablea='tablea';
set @tableb='tableb';

SELECT
   CONCAT(
   "SELECT ",
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', column_name, '` as f',ordinal_position) ORDER BY column_name),
    " FROM `",
    @tablea,
    "`"
    )
FROM   `information_schema`.`columns` 
WHERE  `table_schema`=DATABASE() 
       AND `table_name`=@tablea
INTO @querya;


SELECT
   CONCAT(
   "SELECT ",
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', column_name, '` as f',ordinal_position) ORDER BY column_name),
    " FROM `",
    @tableb,
    "`"
    )
FROM   `information_schema`.`columns` 
WHERE  `table_schema`=DATABASE() 
       AND `table_name`=@tableb
INTO @queryb;



SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`tbl`.`f',ordinal_position,'`') ORDER BY column_name)
FROM   `information_schema`.`columns` 
WHERE  `table_schema`=DATABASE() 
       AND `table_name`=@tablea
INTO @groupbypart;


select concat('select * from ((',@querya,')UNION ALL(',@queryb,')) as tbl group by ',@groupbypart,' having count(*) =1')
into @finalquery;       


PREPARE execquery FROM @finalquery;
EXECUTE execquery;
```

Comment: No this wont work on temporary tables because it wont be added to the scheme information table. But it should be possible to fix by finding another way to get the field names  of an temporary table and rebuild the querya and queryb a bit. maybe you can use showcolumns instead: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-columns.html